# I'm trying to use react-call-detection to detect a missed call number but something is not working

Tags: react-native

Hey there to everyone!

I'm posting my first question so I'll try to be as clear as possible!

I'm building a native android app using react-native(0.61.5), I'm using `setState` hook instead of the classic state and I want to use the react-native-call-detection library(1.8.2).

What is the problem?

```
function startListenerTapped() {
        console.log('start');
        callDetector = new CallDetectorManager((event, number) => {
            console.log(event);
            console.log('inside call detector');
            if (event === 'Missed') {
                console.log(event);
                console.log(number);
                setMissedCaller(number);
            }
        },
            true,
            () => { console.error('access denied') },
            {
                title: 'Phone State Permission',
                message: 'This app needs access to your phone state in order to react and/or to adapt to incoming calls.'
            }
        )
    }
```

I run this function when my component mounts, `callDetector` is set as undefined, I get the 'start' log but when I simulate a call on my AVD nothing happens.
From what I understood the `CallDetectorManager` works like an event listener, right? 
Or do I need to start it every time a call happens?

Another thing I've had a problem with was when I was trying to run a build for the app. I have Gradle 6.0 and I had an error with the react-native-call-detection:

```
  Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:13:7-34
  is also present at [:react-native-call-detection] AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-35 value=(true).
  Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at 
  AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
```

I couldn't really understand what this meant, and the only thing that I've found that solved it was to create a `react-native.config.js` file with this line of code in it:

```
module.exports = { dependencies: { 'react-native-call-detection': { platforms: { android: null, }, }, }, };
```

Another thing that I've only noticed now is that I have a problem with the module of the library.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-call-detection'. 
'c:/folders/projectName/node_modules/react-native-call-detection/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native-call-detection` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-call-detection';`
```

Does anybody knows what that means?!

I think I start to think that it means that I need to find an alternative to this library... AHAHA!

Any kind of help or solution would be more than welcome!
Thanks in advance for everything!